# Python не видит pip3 модули

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, lib

После запуска файла:

> unable to locate directory containing user-installed packages

Все необходимые модули скачаны, но после попытки запуска файла - выдает ошибку выше

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я пытаюсь запустить мой скрипт, но консоль выдает ошибку "unable to locate directory containing user-installed packages" хоть все библиотеки установлены

Comment: Какой файл и как вы пытаетесь запускать? Что именно выдаёт такую ошибку? Приведите больше информации.